# Chrome 85+ Referrer Policy being overridden

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

[As of Chrome 85+](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default), the `Referrer-Policy` header is set to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` by default (if a website hasn't set it explicitly). In my case, I have set this header (via nginx) to `no-referrer-when-downgrade`, but Chrome still overrides this. I have also tried setting this on my web server without luck. My `nginx.conf` contains this line (with other headers omitted):

`more_set_headers 'Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade';`

I've attached a screenshot of a request with the behaviour I'm experiencing. Note how under the **General** tab, we see `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` which is set by Chrome, and under the **Response Headers** tab we see the policy that I set, `no-referrer-when-downgrade`. The one in **General**  precedence here. How can I bypass this behaviour, so that my server's Referrer-Policy is the one used?